# Como descrevo uma fala de personagem?

Tags: gramática

Em um texto narrativo, quando quero colocar uma fala de personagem em um texto, eu uso aspas ou apenas o travessão?

Veja os exemplos.

Com travessão:

> — Filho, você não vai vir comemorar o aniversário do seu avô? Ele tá
>   perguntando de você.

Com aspas:

> "Filho, você não vai vir comemorar o aniversário do seu avô? Ele tá perguntando de você."

Qual a maneira correta?

Comment: aspas se usam para citar a fala de alguém no meio do parágrafo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Travessão é utilizado quando o texto introdutório é seguido de dois pontos (:), por exemplo:

> E Tiago disse:
>   - Eu gostei da comida.

Já as aspas são utilizadas quando nos estamos referindo a uma citação.

> Segundo McGregor, “fazendo um relatório com algumas notas de rodapé".

Comment: Estaria certo numa frase desta forma: `Em seguida pensei “Que ótimo, agora como vou achar as peças? Não dá nem para enxergar direito!”.` colocar um ponto `*.*` numa frase que possui uma citação.

Comment: Não sou professor de português, mas se eu fosse escrever, colocaria um ponto final após a citação.

Comment: [Como pontuar diálogos](http://ligadosbetas.blogspot.com.br/2014/11/como-pontuar-dialogos.html)

Comment: Teria como eu colocar tudo numa mesma frase . Como o travessão , as aspas